# Create a model by passing a relational id from strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an API with Rails 4. There are Org and User models which are related. (below)

Now, I'd like to create new user from parameters like this.

POST /users parameter:

```
{
  "name": "Rails",
  "org_id": 1 // existing Org.id, Org.name == 'Ruby'
}
```

and response should be like this:

```
{
  "name": "Rails",
  "org": {
    "name": "Ruby"
  }
}
```

I'd like to pass `org_id` to `User.create` in order to relate a new user and the existing org. How can I do efficiently with strong parameters?

---

### CODES

models/org.rb

```
class Org < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :org
  validates :org_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class API::UsersController < API::ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.create! create_params # can I do this?
  end

  private

  def create_params
    params.permit(:name, :org_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change *app/models/user.rb*:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :org
  validates :org_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :org
end
```

Now, your params should be like:

```
params = { "name" => "User name here!", "org_attributes" => { "id"=> "1", "name" => "Ruby" } }
```

Here, passing `id` in `org_attributes` will update the existing record for `user`, when you do:

```
@user = User.create! user_params
```

inside your controller, method `user_params`:

```
  private

  def user_params
    params.permit(:name, org_attributes:[:id, :name])
  end
```

And now, `@user = User.create! user_params` should create a user with existing `org` only if you pass `id` inside `org_attributes` params.

Comment: Thanks! Great help.
Quick question: can I change the key name of `org_attributes`?

Comment: Also I don't want to create new org. Can I raise error if the org is not exists?

Comment: Sure, you can raise exception. But you can't change `org_attributes` as Rails expects it to be that way.